How to hide entities and colliders UI in ursina
Problem
How can I hide the Entities and Colliders bar
I attempted to hide the UI with: window.entities.enabled = False, then it gives me a error saying it doesn't work
I really don't know what's the problem and I searched all through the Internet even asked ChatGPT but I can't seem to find a helpful solution
Thank you, Ethan.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This worked for me:
from ursina import Sprite, Texture, Ursina, window, color, Vec3
app = Ursina(size=(1920, 1080))
window.editor_ui.disable()

Source: https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/discussions/570

The simplest way is to pass development_mode=False when you create your Ursina instance.
You could also read the code making this UI and try to do something about it like:

monkey-patching the Window.make_editor_gui bound method to an empty one prior to instantiating Ursina(),
hiding the unneeded GUI entities exposed on the Window instance, for example, entity_counter.

Unfortunately, things get nasty when the class violates the Single Responsibility Principle :(
